# Breadcrumbs for Single Image page

Tags: images, gallery, breadcrumb

As we know in different post we can use some image which we uploaded. This image can be used in many post but it has only one PARENT post.

My question is how to track from which post the user came from.

Example

Home > post 1 > img 2 
Home > post 3 ? img 2

If the image has only one parent post how to find out from which post the user is coming from?

Edit: I think it will be better if I send the parent post Id. To generate the url I use get_attachment_link() . Do you know how I can add additional parameter in the generated link. Because I cannot just add ?parent=14 , because of the different permalinks which Wordpress can use.

Thank you

Comment: In most cases -- but not all -- you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.  See, for instance, [this q&a on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php).

Comment: Thank you for the reply I understood what is the Idea. I think it will be better if I send the parent post Id. To generate the url I use get_attachment_link() . Do you know how I can add additional parameter in the generated link. Because I cannot just add ?parent=14 , because of the different permalinks which wordpress can use.

Comment: Do you want the parent's information to appear in the URL (ie, example.com/parent/attachment), or do you want to display it in a breadcrumb within the content of the attachment page itself?

Comment: Both, if it is in the url I can easily get the parent of the attachment.